# How can you edit bookmarks in an InDesign document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, accessibility, interactive

Got a 50-page INDD presentation, added some bookmarks, which went fine.

But then I need to edit some of the bookmarks, and make them link to other pages. To my surprise, there is no "Edit" option in the Bookmarks panel.

Am I missing something, or is there really no way to edit existing bookmarks ?

Comment: Are you linking directly to text and creating a new bookmark or using paragraph styles to create a table of contents? I do not think there is an edit bookmark option in the bookmark panel.

Comment: Most of these are generated with the TOC feature, then, I added a few manually, but on the wrong pages, and now struggling to fix that, after already reshuffling and grouping with the ones added via TOC.

Comment: mhmm, I am not sure how to edit a manually linked bookmark without needing to re-create it. If you physically move the selected text to another page, the bookmark will update.

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out why they didn't make these editable. I can still fix this in Acrobat, which has all this stuff, but that's just a workaround...

Comment: Maybe helpful?? https://creativepro.com/files/kahrel/indesign/text_anchors.html

Comment: FYI.. I just hit something similar.. What I ended up doing is creating hyperlinks in addition to the existing bookmarks. Both the hyperlinks and bookmarks export to PDF and operate the same basically.. but I can hyperlink *multiple* text strings to the same place (unlike bookmarks in INDD).

Answer (score 0):

If can use the table of contents feature, it will create bookmarks for sections automatically. Others have to be applied manually though.

The name of the bookmarks can be edited in InDesign, from the Bookmarks panel. But the bookmark goes with the text it is associated with, so if that text moves position in the layout, it's still bookmarked to that.

If you're linking to other pages, you need to go to the text you want to link to, select it and go to the Hyperlinks panel > New Hyperlink Destination > Text Anchor. Then go to the text to be linked and add it as a hyperlink, selecting the text anchor you just created.